# Selenium test not running when started by Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have some tests written in pytest with selenium webdriver.  It points to a selenium grid browser node to run the test.  When i run the test from local terminal (py.test test_login.py),  it will connect to the selenium grid correctly,  open up the browesr and run the test.
Switching over to Jenkins,  we set a job to create a build and run the same selenium tests.  However,  it will open the browser (chrome or firefox) but it will not run the test,  it just eventually failed with timeout error.  Everything is on the same network and behind the firewall.  Does anyone know why the test wont run when invoked from Jenkins?  It doesnt seem to be a network issue as it was able to open up the browser on the grid node.

Comment: can you login to your jenkins machine and try doing a telnet to your grid hub ip and check whether are you able to telnet it?

Comment: Is the test being run over a Jenkins slave? If so, has it been installed as a service on the slave machine?

Comment: Is Jenkins running on Linux machine?